# How to place HTML text into OpenOffice spreadsheet using OpenOffice API

Tags: html, openoffice-calc, openoffice-api

**How to place HTML text into OpenOffice spreadsheet using OpenOffice API**

I have found a solution for ODT-Textdocuments.. **(but nothing for a SpreadsheetDocment)**:

> 1. Load odt document where we want to place HTML text.
> 2. Goto place where you want to place HTML text.
> 3. Save HTML text in temp file in the system (maybe it is possible without saving with http URL but I wasn't testing it).
> 4. Insert HTML into odt following this instructions and passing URL to temp HTML file (remember about converting system path to OO path).

There where used the method: insertDocumentFromURL.

I don't know how i can use this method with a spreadsheet.. or is there another solution? For example: `cellText.setHtml("....");`??? Can you or someone help me please???

**Complet Code-Example for OpenOffice TextDocument:**

```
IDocumentService documentService = OOConnection.getDocumentService();
            IDocument document = documentService.constructNewDocument(IDocument.WRITER, new DocumentDescriptor());

            textDocument = (ITextDocument) document;
            String htmlText = "<P></P>" + "<P>Paragraph1</P>" + "NOA HTML Insert Test" + "<b>Bold</b>"
                    + "<H1>Header 1</H1>" + "<P>Paragraph2</P>" + "<CENTER>Center</CENTER>" + "<TABLE>"
                    + "<TR><TD bgcolor=#336699>Cell 1</TD><TD bgcolor=#663399>Cell 2</TD></TR>"
                    + "<TR><TD bgcolor=#123456>the third cell</TD><TD bgcolor=#654321>Cell 4</TD></TR>" + "</TABLE>";
            textDocument.getTextService().getText().setText(htmlText);
            textDocument.getPersistenceService().export(new FileOutputStream("C:/SfH/html.html"), new TextFilter());

            XController xController = textDocument.getXTextDocument().getCurrentController();
            XTextViewCursorSupplier xTextViewCursorSupplier = (XTextViewCursorSupplier) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                    XTextViewCursorSupplier.class, xController);
            XTextViewCursor xViewCursor = xTextViewCursorSupplier.getViewCursor();
            XTextCursor xTextCursor = xViewCursor.getText().createTextCursorByRange(xViewCursor.getStart());
            XDocumentInsertable xDocumentInsertable = (XDocumentInsertable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                    XDocumentInsertable.class, xTextCursor);

            xDocumentInsertable.insertDocumentFromURL(
                    URLAdapter.adaptURL(new File("C:/SfH/html.html").getAbsolutePath()), new PropertyValue[0]);
            textDocument.update();
```

Andi